# Can I get attributes of model in relation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

For example in model Post, I have such relation:

```
public function voters()
{
     return $this->morphMany(Voter::class, 'entity');
}
```

Can I get attributes and fields of post entity from which I get voters?

Comment: Please could you explain what data you want to get exactly and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access properties of the Post entity,

> You may also retrieve the owner of a polymorphic relation from the
>   polymorphic model by accessing the name of the method that performs
>   the call to morphTo. In our case, that is the  commentable method on
>   the Comment model. So, we will access that method as a dynamic
>   property:

```
<?php 
$comment = App\Comment::find(1);
$commentable = $comment->commentable;
```

> The commentable relation on the Comment model will return either a
>   Post or Video instance, depending on which type of model owns the
>   comment.

For your example, you have to add a method in your Voter entity, and call it for example `votable` :

```
<?php
/**
 * Get all of the owning commentable models.
 */
public function votable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Then, when you retrieve a voter, and want to get the "owner" (in this case the post), you will call :

```
<?php 
$voter = App\Voter::find(1);
$votable = $voter->votable;
```

And `$votable` will be an instance of the owner of the vote (you Post). From there, you can access its properties as you would normally do.